# Do morphisms of locally ringed spaces which agree on stalks agree on the whole of the locally ringed space?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, ringed-spaces

Let $f,g:X\rightarrow Y$ be morphisms of locally ringed spaces, such that the topological maps $f$ and $g$ are identical, and the maps of sheaves $f^\sharp,g^\sharp:\mathcal{O}_Y\rightarrow f_*\mathcal{O}_X$ agree on stalks. By this I mean that for all $x\in X$, the maps $f_x,g_x:(\mathcal{O}_Y)_{f(x)}\rightarrow (\mathcal{O}_X)_x$ agree. I want to know if $f^\sharp=g^\sharp$.

The stacks project seems to use this fact [here](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01L1) in Lemma 26.23.7, but maybe I'm wrong.

The way I think of the map $f_x:(\mathcal{O}_Y)_{f(x)}\rightarrow (\mathcal{O}_X)_x$ is as a composition of the stalk maps $f^\sharp_{f(x)}:(\mathcal{O}_Y)_{f(x)}\rightarrow (f_*\mathcal{O}_X)_{f(x)}$, $(f^*)_x:(f_*\mathcal{O}_X)_{f(x)}\rightarrow (\mathcal{O}_X)_x$.
The first map is just the usual induced map on stalks, and the second map is given by:
$$[U,s]_{f(x)}\longmapsto [f^{-1}(U),s]_x$$
which is well defined by some universal property of colimits. Since $f$ and $g$ are equal, its clear that $(f^*)_x=(g^*)_x$, so we have that:
$$(f^*)_x\circ (f^\sharp)_{f(x)}=(f^*)_x\circ g^\sharp_{f(x)}$$
and so I guess if $(f^*)_x$ is a monomorphism, we have have that $(f^\sharp)_{f(x)}=g^\sharp_{f(x)}$ for all $y\in \text{im } f$, but a) I dont know think that $(f^*)_x$ is a monomorphism in general, and b) this only shows they agree on some of the stalks not all of them.

Am I missing something here? Perhaps my map of stalks is not correct?

Comment: What are you asking? Are you asking if $f^\#=g^\#$?

Comment: @AlexMathers yes exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show that $f^\sharp=g^\sharp\colon\mathcal{O}_Y\to\mathcal f_*{O}_X$, it suffices to show that the adjoint maps $f_\sharp,g_\sharp\colon f^{-1}\mathcal{O}_Y\to\mathcal{O}_X$ are equal. This can be checked on stalks, so we need to show that, for all $x\in X$, the maps $(f_\sharp)_x,(g_\sharp)_x\colon \mathcal{O}_{Y,f(x)}\cong(f^{-1}\mathcal{O}_Y)_x\to\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ are equal. But this is the assumption you started with.

Comment: How is this the assumption I started with? And does this imply that $(f^*)_x$ is a monomorphism?

Comment: You stated in the first paragraph: ''By this I mean that for all $x\in X$, the maps $f_x,g_x\colon (\mathcal{O}_Y)_{f(x)}\to (\mathcal{O}_X)_x$ agree.'' This is what I use at the end. It doesn't imply that $(f^*_x)$ is a monomorphism, as this is generally false: if $f^{-1}(f(x))$ contains finitely many points and admits a covering by disjoint open sets, each of which contains exactly one of the points in $f^{-1}(f(x))$, then $(f_*\mathcal{O}_X)_{f(x)}$ is a product $\prod_{z\in f^{-1}(x)} \mathcal{O}_{X,z}$, and the projection map from this to $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ is generally not injective.

Comment: Let $[U,s]\in \mathcal f_*O_{X,f(x)}$, and suppose that $f^*_x([U,s])=0$, then there exists an open subset $W$ of $f^{-1}(U)$ containing $x$ such that $s|_W=0$. Since $f$ is continuous, we can find an open neighborhood $V$ of $f(x)$ such that $f^{-1}(V)\subset W$, so it follows that $s|_{f^{-1}(V)}=0$. But that’s now a restriction map in $f_*\mathcal{O}_X$, so $[U,s]=[V,s|_V]=0$. Does that not imply that $f^*_x$ is injective?

Comment: Ok nevermind, my whole thought process in the preceding comment is flawed. Is there a way to show this without appealing to the inverse image functor? I am filling in the gaps on my course notes and I'd like to be able to use this result before working with the inverse image sheaf.